# In my android appciation i want to display textview like below image?

Tags: android

I want to diaplay Textview as per image below can any one help me.is it possible in Android or not.

[image]

Comment: Let me see if I understand right, you want to display a textView below an image?

Comment: Why exactly do you need a TextView for this ? Why not simply use an image ? Because it looks like this is static content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `transparent` text view:

```
<TextView 
...
android:background="@null"
...
/>
```

Then if you align it correctly in layout,it seems as per of your image.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the size of the Text.You can change it using SpannableStringBuilder.

```
SpannableStringBuilder spanTxt = new SpannableStringBuilder("Different");
spanTxt.append("text1");
//make the textsize 2 times.
spanTxt.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), spanTxt.length() - " text1".length(), spanTxt.length(), 0);
```

And Now set it As the text for your TextView.

To get the border for the textView,You can create a drawable like this and set it as the background for the TextView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/grey"/>
<!-- "#5D2E8C"  -->
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />       <!-- background to the border -->
    <padding
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp" />
    <corners android:radius="0dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with a RelativeLayout by using the following properties in TextViews

```
 android:layout_marginLeft
 android:layout_marginRight
 android:layout_below
 android:layout_above
 android:layout_toLeftOf
 android:layout_toRightOf
```

- use different TextView for each word ( Large, medium and small text views)

  ie , by setting the following  attributes in text views

  ```
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
  ```
- give the "boundary-image" as a background to the relative layout

Answer (score 0):

Consider using either an AbsoluteLayout or RelativeLayout for dynamic content. Alternatively you can draw text to a bitmap via the Canvas class and then simply draw the bitmap.

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
c.drawText("Text", 0.0f, 0.0f, null); //Probably paint cannot be null
```

If your content is static however you should probably just apply Perera's approach.

[RelativeLayout - Android.com Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html)

[AbsoluteLayout - Android.com Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html)